# Adding glyphicons in textarea is showing text instead of glyphicon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

When we click on glyphicon I need a functionality to get then entered into the textarea dynamically.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Click Event of glyphicon class  
  $(document).on('click','.glyphicon',function(){
             
   var previous_content = $.trim($("#area").html());  
   var new_icon = '<span class="'+$(this).attr('class')+'"></span>';
      
    //*****The below method of create element is also not working
             //var new_icon = document.createElement("span");
       //new_icon.setAttribute('class', $(this).attr('class'));
      
   var new_content = previous_content+new_icon;
   $("#area").html(new_content);
      
  });
    
});
```

```css
.glyphicon {
     cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="area" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea>
<p>Asterisk icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></p>
<p>Copyright-mark icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span></p>     
</body>
</html>
```

Before searching please use snippet to see the actual issue.

Comment: Please scroll down the snippet to see the clickable glyphicons.

Comment: You can not insert icons directly in text box.... you should go for ASCII format

Comment: @sunil: I am making a custom editor. Can you please give an example ? Because i think it should work

Comment: @sunil we can imagine this as emoticons.. Like we add emoticons into the content of textarea.. Exactly like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't display rendered HTML in a `TextArea`.

As a work around you can add a `<div>` with the `contenteditable` attrbibute set to `true`

```
<div id="area" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

You can also use a `<pre>` tag if you want it to look and feel more like a TextArea.

Here's a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Click Event of glyphicon class  
  $(document).on('click', '.glyphicon', function() {

    var previous_content = $.trim($("#area").html());
    var new_icon = '<span class="' + $(this).attr('class') + '"></span>';

    //*****The below method of create element is also not working
    //var new_icon = document.createElement("span");
    //new_icon.setAttribute('class', $(this).attr('class'));

    var new_content = previous_content + new_icon;
    $("#area").html(new_content);

  });

});
```

```css
.glyphicon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="area" contenteditable="true">This &lt;div&gt; tag is editable just like a TextArea.<br /></div>
  <p>Asterisk icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></p>
  <p>Copyright-mark icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help. :).. One thing more i just noticed that if we want to insert the glyphicon in between of some text.. As now it is adding at last position whether the cursor is in center. Thanks in advance for further help

Comment: Not a problem. That gets a little more tricky, you could find a targetElement and insert the new icon before it `previous_content[0].insertBefore(targetElement, new_icon);` If you are having new issues you should open a different question so this one stays on topic and relevant to your question. Also, take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can put html markup into an `input` or `textarea`, but it won't be parsed as such. (It would be a huge security hole if it were!) Instead, the input is just...text. So you need another step if you want to use html from that text.

In order to render the icon spans as actual styled html spans, you'd need to capture them from the input field, parse them, and then show the rendered version. You could look into how Markdown-based or other WYSIWYG editors handle this, but basically, `<span>` inside an actual input will always just be `<span>`, the string.

Comment: Can you show with an example. I agreed that ckeditor and all are working with glyphicons.. But the thing is how ?.. So it would be great if you can show this using a test snippet.